# Custom launcher doesn't fire some apps

Tags: android, android-launcher

I writing a custom launcher application on Android OS for a company. It works quite well, I can start most of the apps. The problem is with the word: most of :) Some of the apps won't launch. Apps like: Instagram, Facebook Messenger. When I press the icon, it is started, but getting closed immediately, without any error message. Do you have any idea to help me ? 
Code:

> ```
>         Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(item.getApplicationPackageName());
>         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
>         if (intent != null) {
>             getActivity().startActivity(intent);
>         }
> ```

Thank you very much,
K

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had found the solution:

just add the following Flags to intent

> ```
>         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
>         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> ```